# Show that $|A|\le |B|$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $A \subseteq B$, show that $|A|\le |B|$.

I know I need to show that $f: A \to B$ is injective.

This is what I have done so far:

Since $A\subseteq B$, there exists an injection f such that $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in A $. By definition, $|A| \le |B|$.

I think this is all I need to do. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The inclusion function $\iota \colon A \to B; x \mapsto x$ is injective, since $\iota(x) = \iota(x') \iff x = x'$ :).

Comment: You need to choose a function $f$ before you can show it is injective.  It won't be true for just any arbitrary $f$.

Comment: Andrew: what reason would you give that x=x' from your statement?

Answer (score 1):

Claim: If $A \subseteq B$, then $|A| \le |B|$.

Proof: As you pointed out, it suffices to show that there exists *some* function $f$ such that $f: A \rightarrow B$ is injective. The identity function is a candidate for satisfying this criteria, and we need to show it is indeed injective. The identity function $f: A \rightarrow B$ is defined as $f(x) = x$ for any $x \in A$.

Suppose that $x, y \in A$ and $f(x) = f(y)$. We need to show that $x = y$ to show that $f$ is injective. Clearly this is true, since we have $f(x) = x = f(y) = y$. $\square$

Answer (score 0):

Just map every element to itself: $f(x) = x$

Comment: So, can I just say that let $x, x' \in A$ such that $f(x)=f(x')$?

Comment: try again lily if you have that then it wouldn't be injective. you want $f(x)=x$ as in if $x\in A$ then $x\in B$ so $x \to x$, $\forall x\in A$.

Comment: No, you want each element to map to a unique element. Saying f(x) = f(x') is exactly what you want to avoid. Instead, say f(x) = x, and f(x') = x'.  Or just in general: f(x) = x for *all* x.